# How can convert System::Int32 to wchar_t*

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, wchar-t, int32

I have this piece of code:

```
int casted_dbValue=3;
wchar_t* nativeData=(wchar_t*)casted_dbValue;
```

it is incorrect conversion between `int` to const `wchar_t*`. How can deal with this error?

Comment: @Cody Gray: if it is impossible, can i do the conversion between `System::Int32` to `wchar_t` ! how!

Comment: Why are you trying to take an integer value and cast it to a pointer?  What are you trying to do here?  It's not possible to give a good answer without knowing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the [`_itow` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yakksftt.aspx)?

```
wchar_t * _itow(
                int value,
                wchar_t *str,
                int radix
                );
```

Or, the more secure version, [`_itow_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0we9x30h.aspx).

The first parameter (`value`) is the integer value to be converted, the second is the string result, and the third is the base of the numeric value. It returns a pointer to the `str` value.

Comment: this the code ` wchar_t* nativeData=_itow( casted_dbValue,wchar_t *nativeData1, 10 );` and i got the error `Error 2 error C2062: type 'wchar_t' unexpected` !

Comment: @user: That's not how pointers work... Your function call is incorrect. You're going to have a very hard time writing C++ code if you don't have any better understanding of pointers than that. I recommend picking up a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: i know in general how to use pointers.. ! what was the problem, if u give me hent it will be better than the books,, thanks